# Upgrade crash samba4 error

Tags: samba

upgrade to Natty failed to finish, with an error related to samba4, failed to load modules from /usr/lib/samba/ldb.

Now I am unable to update or run Synaptic. How can I fix this?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to fix this is probably to run "dpkg --purge samba4" in a terminal to uninstall Samba 4. We are also working on an update which fixes this particular error.

Samba 4 is an experimental version of Samba. If you just need file sharing, I would recommend using the "samba" package (Samba 3) instead.